# MySQL. Select years range

Tags: php, mysql

I've got database listed below. As you can see, there is a range of years for each model. For example, `Infiniti    EX35` in range of `2008-2010`

```
Infiniti    EX35    2010    3.5 V6
Infiniti    EX35    2009    3.5 V6
Infiniti    EX35    2008    3.5 V6
Infiniti    EX37    2007    3.7i V6
Infiniti    EX37    2008    3.7i V6
Infiniti    EX37    2009    3.7i V6
Infiniti    EX37    2010    3.7i V6
Infiniti    FX35    2003    3.5 V6
Infiniti    FX35    2004    3.5 V6
Infiniti    FX35    2005    3.5 V6
Infiniti    FX35    2006    3.5 V6
Infiniti    FX35    2007    3.5 V6
Infiniti    FX35    2008    3.5 V6
```

How can I make compact selection like this?

```
Infiniti    EX35    2008-2010   3.5 V6
Infiniti    EX37    2007-2010   3.7i V6
Infiniti    FX35    2003-2008   3.5 V6
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Make, Model, 
    CASE
      WHEN MIN(Year) = MAX(Year) 
        THEN MIN(Year)
      ELSE CONCAT(MIN(Year), '-', MAX(Year))
    END As Year,
    OtherColumns
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Make, Model, OtherColumns
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
Select Make, Model, Concat(Min(Year),'-',Max(Year)) As Range, EngineType 
From Table
Group By Make, Model
```

Comment: +1 Missed EngineType in the GROUP BY, but it's the answer I was in the process of typing in

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, imo it would not be a good idea to put a range in one field -- it becomes very hard to handle and besides it's unnormalized. Isntead, make two fields "start_year" and "end_year," which makes it easy to select on and also makes things normalized.

-- pete