# MySQL. List years between a range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I made some research and found this question that do the opposite that I want (they want to create range for a complete list of years for automobiles).

[MySQL. Select years range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437052/mysql-select-years-range)

In my case I want to list the years but my years are in range.

---

**Updated info**

Query

```
SELECT make, model, begin_year, end_year, motor
FROM general_information
LIMIT 2;
```

(I didn't put relation between tables to reduce space and be specific)

---

My data (just two rows for simplicity):

> | make | model  | begin_year   | end_year | motor |
>
> | Chevrolet | Cavalier  | 2002   | 2005 | 4 Cil 2.2 Lts |
>
> | Ford | Explorer | 1995 | 1996 | 6 Cil 3.3 Lts |
>
> ...

And I want to get MySQL query that look like this

> | Chevrolet |  Cavalier | 2002 |  4 Cil 2.2 Lts |
>
> | Chevrolet |  Cavalier | 2003 |  4 Cil 2.2 Lts |
>
> | Chevrolet |  Cavalier | 2004 |  4 Cil 2.2 Lts |
>
> | Chevrolet |  Cavalier | 2005 |  4 Cil 2.2 Lts |
>
> | Ford | Explorer | 1995  | 6 Cil 3.3 Lts |
>
> | Ford | Explorer | 1996 | 6 Cil 3.3 Lts |

I have tried a couple of MySQL queries that involve CASE, MIN, MAX but none of this have give me the desired result.
**I think that the answer use a subquery, so I'm going to keep trying**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is that data a table row? or a single entry?

Comment: Post query(ies) that you tried.

Comment: Issues of data display are generally best handled in the presentation layer/application-level code (assuming you have that)

Comment: Ready the info has been updated..let me post you my alternative queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must solve this in SQL layer, and you can't change your `general_information` table schema to normalize the year data, my suggestion would be to introduce a new `year_list` table that you can join against.  This table would be pretty simple:

```
year_value
1900
1901
1902
...
2020
```

Obviously you would use a range of years that is appropriate for you

Then you join against this table:

```
SELECT
  gi.make AS make,
  gi.model AS model,
  y.year_value AS model_year,
  gi.motor AS motor
FROM general_information AS gi
INNER JOIN year_list AS y ON y.year_value BETWEEN gi.begin_year AND gi.end_year
ORDER BY make ASC, model ASC, model_year ASC, motor ASC
```

That being said, I think you would be much better served to simply remove the year data from the main table and put it into a separate table for joining.  This would produce a structure like this:

```
general_information
-------------------
id <=  create a new autoincrementing primary key field
make
model
motor
```

Provide a unique index across the make, model, and motor fields

```
general_information_to_years
----------------------------
gi_id <= foreign key to id field in general_information table
year_value
```

You would provide a compound primary key on these two columns

This would represent a more properly normalized database structure.

The query would then look like:

```
SELECT
  gi.make AS make,
  gi.model AS model,
  giy.year_value AS model_year,
  gi.motor AS motor
FROM general_information AS gi
INNER JOIN general_information_to_years AS giy ON gi.id = giy.gi_id
ORDER BY make ASC, model ASC, model_year ASC, motor ASC
```

Comment: Mike you're solution help me a lot...I found what I was looking for, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query.

```
   SELECT make,model,begin_year + years.incYears as year,motor
FROM
 (SELECT (y1.value + y2.value + y3.value + y4.value + y5.value) as incYears
  FROM
  (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 1)y1,
  (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 2)y2,
  (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 4)y3,
  (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 8)y4,
  (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 16)y5
  )years
CROSS JOIN general_information
WHERE begin_year+years.incYears <= end_year
ORDER BY make,year
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/176fbf/1/0)

Comment: I make a try but was difficult integrate it in my query...thanks for your demo and your help